# Monitoring users activities on Gitlab-CE

Tags: gitlab

I want to know if there's any possibilities to monitor users activities on different projects on Gitlab CE.
I want to know who:

- who has cloned a project via git clone command?
- who has downloaded a project as a zip/tar file via web interface of gitlab?

Thank you